# MongoDB: Change block_compressor for existing collection

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I have a server running with wiredTiger storage engine, but without compression enabled globally. Now I want to change the "block_compressor" option for a single collection to use "snappy".
According to the mongoDB documentation this is possible while creating a new collection using "db.createCollection()", but how can I perform this step for an existing one? (Maybe for new replica set members before initial sync)

Since initial sync between non-wiredTiger and wiredTiger members in a replica set is performed on a per-document level (and not by copying the files), this should be possible...

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#specify-storage-engine-options

Comment: This question is "off-topic" for StackOverflow, which is a programming questions site. Your question should instead be asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead, which is more suited to database administration and configuration questions.

Comment: Good point. Will post it on dba.